# In Playwright for Python, how do I get elements relative to ElementHandle (children, parent, grandparent, siblings)?

Tags: python, dom, handle, playwright, playwright-python

In playwright-python I know I can get an `elementHandle` using `querySelector()`.

Example (sync):

```
from playwright import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = browser_type.launch()
        page = browser.newPage()  
        page.goto('https://duckduckgo.com/')
        element = page.querySelector('input[id=\"search_form_input_homepage\"]')
```

How do I get the an element relative to this based on this `elementHandle`? I.e. the parent, grandparent, siblings, children handles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Original answer:**

Using `querySelector()` / `querySelectorAll` with
[XPath (XML Path Language)](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) lets you retrieve the `elementHandle` (respectively a collection of handles). Generally speaking, *XPath* can be used to navigate through elements and attributes in an XML document.

```
from playwright import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = browser_type.launch(headless=False)
        page = browser.newPage()
        page.goto('https://duckduckgo.com/')
        element = page.querySelector('input[id=\"search_form_input_homepage\"]')
        
        parent = element.querySelector('xpath=..')
        grandparent = element.querySelector('xpath=../..')
        siblings = element.querySelectorAll('xpath=following-sibling::*')
        children = element.querySelectorAll('xpath=child::*')

        browser.close()
```

**Update (2022-07-22):**

It seems that `browser.newPage()` is deprecated, so in newer versions of playwright, the function is called `browser.new_page()` (note the different function name).

Optionally create a browser context first (and close it afterwards) and call `new_page()` on that context.

The way the children/parent/grandparent/siblings are accessed stays the same.

```
from playwright import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = browser_type.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto('https://duckduckgo.com/')
        element = page.querySelector('input[id=\"search_form_input_homepage\"]')
        
        parent = element.querySelector('xpath=..')
        grandparent = element.querySelector('xpath=../..')
        siblings = element.querySelectorAll('xpath=following-sibling::*')
        children = element.querySelectorAll('xpath=child::*')

        context.close()
        browser.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

The Accepted answer is in older version of playwright.Use the following format for current version it will work.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = browser_type.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context()
        page =context.new_page()
        page.goto('https://duckduckgo.com/')
        element = page.query_selector('input[id=\"search_form_input_homepage\"]')
        
        parent = element.query_selector('xpath=..')
        grandparent = element.query_selector('xpath=../..')
        siblings = element.query_selector_all('xpath=following-sibling::*')
        children = element.query_selector_all('xpath=child::*')

        context.close()
        browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using query_selector is depricated now.
Instead, use

```
child_element = page.locator('input[id=\"search_form_input_homepage\"]')
parent = page.locator('div').filter(has=child_element)
grandparent = page.locator('xpath=../..')
siblings = page.locator('xpath=following-sibling::*')
children = page.locator('xpath=child::*')
```

[See link](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/next/other-locators#parent-element-locator)